# Swift customize table view cell unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, customization, uitableview

I want to customize a table view cell, so I created a new file like the following and did necessary steps mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html

DetailTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class DetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

But when I write var details =Detail(), it will report **Use of unresolved identifier 'Detail'**.

WHY? I just follow the tutorial.

```
class CurrentViewController: UIViewController{

var details=[Detail]()
...
}
```

Comment: Detail is not defined try var details=[DetailTableViewCell]()

Comment: Did you define the Detail model object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define `Detail` model object.

You have to work with this first:

[image]